# Android pause and resume upload

Tags: android, file-upload

I'd like to create a pause and resume system for my uploading component. So far I'm able to directly and continuously upload a video to ym remote server with the following code:

```
private void uploadVideo(String videoPath) throws Exception
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SEVER_ENDPOINT);

    FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
    StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: " + videoPath);
    StringBody description = new StringBody("Short description");

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
    reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
    reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

How could I pause the upload, save the progress. Do whatever I want (Like killing the app) and then when I restart it, resume it and continue to upload the missing part ?

Tahnks for your precious help.

Comment: first, you need to check if your server has an API for such resumable uploads. If yes, you should use this API to do what you want, if no, nothing can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a way to achieve to do that, thanlks to `Kienco` from Github.

Here is a link to his code: https://github.com/kienco/android-simpl3r

Comment: Hi Manitoba, was this solution working for any server or it was restricted for amazon s3 only? I want to implement this pause/resume of uploading in my app having different server api's.

Comment: Hello. It should work everywhere. Just don't forget to implement it on your server. If you use `PHP`, you could do it like that: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/04/resumeupload/

Comment: hey, can you describe it in detail that what to implement on my server, is there any services which i would be needed to use from amazon(either free or paid)? I have my client's server APIs & my android code. I want to implement pause/resume file uploading functionality from android, So if i use this library then what are the access key, bucket key or secret code etc. is this something like needed to register on amazon? can you put me in right direction?

Comment: I am also searching a solution for the same problem. I can't implement the the amazon s3 server side code in php .

Comment: it would be very nice if someone come up and explains all this stuffs for client and server implementation (nice if android+nodejs) it will help the begineers like me

Comment: i am facing same problem. i am uploading files on ovh cloud server. but not been able to resume/pause upload